# How to add new value to index array in php 5.6

Tags: php, arrays

This is my array with values:

```
Array ( 
[1] => Array ( [id_category] => 2 [name] => Główna ) 
[2] => Array ( [id_category] => 61 [name] => Test )
```

To each index I want to add new key and value. For example: "id_parent". So the results should be something like that:

```
Array ( 
    [1] => Array ( [id_category] => 2 [name] => Główna [id_parent] => 0) 
    [2] => Array ( [id_category] => 61 [name] => Test [id_parent] => 0)
```

How to add new key ? Below I show my php code with comments

```
$array = $this->getAllCategoriesFromShop();//array like in example
        foreach ($array AS $addValue)
        {
            $addValue[] = array('id_parent' => '3');
            $result = array_merge($addValue, $array);
        }
        return $result;
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `&` (pass by reference) to update the current array element on `foreach`

```
$array = array ( 
    array ( "id_category" => 2, "name" => 'Główna' ), 
    array ( "id_category" => 61, "name" => 'Test' )
);

foreach ($array as &$addValue)
{
    $addValue['id_parent'] = 3;
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r( $array );
echo "</pre>";
```

This will result to:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id_category] => 2
            [name] => Główna
            [id_parent] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id_category] => 61
            [name] => Test
            [id_parent] => 3
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    $array = $this->getAllCategoriesFromShop();
    foreach ($array AS $key => $value)
    {
        $array[$key]['id_parent'] = 3;
    }
    return $array;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php

$data =
[
    ['fruit'=>'orange'],
    ['fruit'=>'apple']
];

foreach($data as $k=>$v)
    $data[$k]['veg'] = 'courgette';

var_export($data);
```

Output:

```
array (
    0 => 
    array (
    'fruit' => 'orange',
    'veg' => 'courgette',
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
    'fruit' => 'apple',
    'veg' => 'courgette',
    ),
)
```